# Multiple logical filters in a WFS request with OpenLayers 2.13.1

Tags: javascript, wfs, openlayers-2

Is it possible, and if so how, to use multiple logical filters in a wfs request?

For example I have a attribute, type_id that should be 1, 2 or 3.

```
var wfsTypeFilters = [
    new OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison({
        type: OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.EQUAL_TO,
        property: "type_id",
        value: 1
    }),
    new OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison({
        type: OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.EQUAL_TO,
        property: "type_id",
        value: 2
    }),
    new OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison({
        type: OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.EQUAL_TO,
        property: "type_id",
        value: 3
    })
];
```

And then I have an attribute called name that should **not** be empty

```
var wfsNameIsNotNullFilter = [
    new OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison({
        type: OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.NOT_EQUAL_TO,
        property: "type_id",
        value :""
    }
)];
```

After thtis I tried to create two different logical filters. And when combining them I get error:
Uncaught Filter writing not supported for rule type: undefined

```
var parent_type_filter = new OpenLayers.Filter.Logical({
    type: OpenLayers.Filter.Logical.OR,
    filters: wfsTypeFilters
});


var parent_filter = new OpenLayers.Filter.Logical({
    type: OpenLayers.Filter.Logical.AND,
    filters: [parent_type_filter, wfsNameIsNotNullFilter]
});
```

If I would have written a sql query this would have been easy by using parentheses

```
WHERE (type_id = 1 OR type_id = 2 OR type_id = 3 ) AND (name != "")
```

Br
Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I would check if the attribut "name" is really an empty string or if it's a null value what you are looking for. In this case you would have to use

```
  new OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison({
        type: OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.IS_NULL,
        property: "type_id"
    });
```

You can have a look at a combination of the filtertypes you are using in your example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/expedio/eef7n2sy/

Update1: Here one example for server-side filtering:

http://jsfiddle.net/expedio/4L9om0rc/

PS: i also encountered problems while using OL 2.11 . after switching to 2.13.1 the problem disappeared.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the response.

Perhaps I wasn't to clear in my question. 
What I want is to filter the wfs request on the server. The example you posted uses Strategy.Filter and isn't that only filtering on the client? 
At least that's the only thing I manage to filter.

Comment: right. I just added the jsfiddle with server side filtering while requesting the wfs ;) ( http://jsfiddle.net/expedio/4L9om0rc/ )

Comment: I'm not quite sure exactly what I did wrong in the beginning. But thanks to the code in your last fiddle example I now managed to get my code to work.
Big thanks to you Thomas!

Comment: your welcome ;) please don't forget to mark the question as answered so it does not appear in the unanswered section anymore